# OdbcDataReader limit

Tags: .net, odbcdatareader

I wrote a small program to help me extract information from a timeseries database and save them in a text file. I am using .net system.data.odbc.odbcdatareader class . I have observed that it limits the number of rows stored on it to 100.000. When I run my query to the database it return more than 100.000 records but the Odbcdatareader seems to store just 100.000 records. I have look for some help in the online documentation but couldn't find any tips.

Here is the code I am using (just the lines that matters)

```
Dim sw As System.IO.StreamWriter
...
cmd = New Odbc.OdbcCommand(Query, conn)
...
XRecords = cmd.ExecuteReader()
...
sw = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(strFile, False, utf8WithoutBom)
...
While (XRecords.Read())
     sw.WriteLine(XRecords.GetValue(0).ToString())
End While
sw.Close()
```

Does anyone has any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Don't know the answer, but a workaround may be to use the feature of your underlying RDBMS to batch the reading of records (e.g., `SELECT * FROM (query) WHERE ROWNUM > startIndex AND ROWNUM < startIndex + pageSize`). Then read and write them one batch at a time. Might see better performance too...

Comment: I did something like this to solve my problem but it doesn't seem to be an elegant solution. There should be a better way to solve this.